# Keep receiving foreign-key error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm receiving a foreign key error every time I attempt to insert into the `Book_Written_By` table.

The SQL for this table is:

```
`CREATE TABLE `Book_Written_By` (
`title` char ( 255 ),
`ISBN`  varchar2,
`fname` char ( 255 ),
`lname` char ( 255 ),
FOREIGN KEY(`title`,`ISBN`) REFERENCES `Book_Belongs_To`(`title`,`ISBN`),
FOREIGN KEY(`fname`,`lname`) REFERENCES `Author`(`fname`,`lname`)
);
```

and SQL for Book_Belongs_To is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Book_Belongs_To` (
`section_name`  char ( 255 ),
`year`  integer,
`title` char ( 255 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`ISBN`  varchar2 NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`publisher` char ( 255 ),
`inventory` integer NOT NULL,
`price` float NOT NULL,
`edition`   char ( 255 ),
PRIMARY KEY(`ISBN`),
FOREIGN KEY(`section_name`) REFERENCES `Section`(`name`)
);'
```

Error:

> foreign key mismatch - "Book_Written_By" referencing "Book_Belongs_To":

```
INSERT INTO `Book_Written_By` (`title`, `ISBN`, `fname`, `lname`) 
VALUES ('Fundamentals of Database Systems', '0-8053-1755-4', 'Ramez A. ', 'Elmasri'); `
```

Any assist would be helpful!

Comment: Why not make your life easier??  Create an auto-increment primary key on each table, then create the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert non integer value `0-8053-1755-4` into `ISBN` which is defined as integer.

Comment: Hi there,I've made some changes above, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Are you sure this is mysql ? Because varchar2 is an Oracle type. If this is indeed mysql, replace all your char (can work with mysql but is not appropriate in your case) and varchar2 by varchar type

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a mistake, ISBN is defined as an integer so 0-8053-1755-4 will evaluate to -9812. Probably you should write 805317554 or use single-quotes and varchar2. If that isn't the error, please double-check that you have a book_written_by with the specified title and ISBN.

Comment: Hi there,I've made some changes above, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Please show what you have in the tables when you start, i.e. the insert into book_belongs_to. If the tables are empty and the insert you have posted is the first you should get an error as the constraint is doing its intended job!

Answer (score 0):

`ISBN` is integer and the value given is not an integer. Change schema to char for ISBN field.

With your the given schema, you will get invalid values for ISBN.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cd19f/1/0

Comment: Hi there,I've made some changes above, but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if the value inserted into "ISBN" column meets attribute datatype. And most importantly make sure that the key that are used as FK at table "Book_Written_By" should be declared as unique in its own table. For example, "title" field should be declare unique in its table "Book_Belongs_To"

Comment: Hi there,I've made some changes above, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Foreign Key relationship refers the parent table(Book_Belongs_To) to hold the central data and child table (Book_Written_By) referring the identical values of the parent table. Before inserting into  table "Book_Written_By" make sure that the foreign key values exist in the parent table "Book_Belongs_To"  first. 

Here `title` = 'Fundamentals of Database Systems' and   
`ISBN` = '0-8053-1755-4' should exist in the "Book_Belongs_To" table first.